# Why can't I save a pipeline without running it?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I am midway through creating a pipeline I might want to save it without running it.

However there is no "save only" button.
Why not?

[image: Save and Run]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason is that because the YAML pipelines it's a `.yaml` file in your repository, that triggered when the repo changed. so when you create a new pipeline, the `.yaml` file it's pushed into the repo and immediately the pipeline triggered (like every repo change from now on).

You can change in the `.yaml` file the `trigger` to `none` and then you can only save:

```
trigger: none
```

Comment: That makes sense. Is there some way I can turn off the trigger to see if that is the reason?

Comment: Try to put this in the yaml: `trigger: none`, this is No-CI configuration.

Comment: When I changed the trigger from master to none the button changed to "Save"

Comment: It also explains why when I "save and run" it asks whether I would prefer to create a pull request.

Comment: I would call that a fair case for leaving build definitions outside the repo, as they are inherent to Azure Pipelines anyway and don't port anywhere. It would be also nice if the classic editor in Pipelines just generated YAML so you could use both UI and YAML. I know many of the tasks are available with UI in the YAML helper, but it doesn't seem that seamless, e.g a trigger set in YAML can be overridden in UI but not modified. I also hope the term 'classic editor' does not imply future deprecation of the UI tools.I should probably comment on this elsewhere..